# generate_presigned_url generated URL not accessible to the public Internet users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I'd like to generate a presigned URL for objects that I just uploaded to my S3 buckets using code here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

but somehow the presigned URLs that I generated isn't accessible from the open public Internet which always says "AccessDenied".

1. When I logged into my AWS console and click `Share with a presigned URL` button, that'll generate a url which the open Internet users can use to download;
2. I noticed it's quite different from the one created from the console than the one that I generated using boto3 python code:

The URL generated from the console looks like this:

```
https://cool-analysis-artifacts.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/0012d668-13c9-11ee-a2f0-5602f45624de/picture-4079.png?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEOj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMSJHMEUCIACEtKpoR%2BlEqdpoHWb1RVrfwBrByTGLYanx24UT1DlLAiEAhvqWPU9rBBjh6oPoFcmhWF8OYummjOd9TvwmBeoS7R0q8AQIYRACGgwwMjE1NDI3NDIxMDAiDCRM66a0CJAH3n63CirNBHBievkO%2BeReu4jS4Pniyusbk%2BkQ2L%2BVXh9kALEvqz65%2B9qAG2vlPMO9Mdl0XkuF%2FqLF3p4UBWf0yE1wDUPaY0Ly0R6J6MNz9y0%2Bdrg6hAOCbjOpsNi7gxzuMr8UlrU3vBCplcx5sGMdUMcXaCBj8%2Bgj2xEa15arGvZvS1xC%2Fb%2BRH5LPropdeep4DHGNlsdryfk0UkTAIsZ9Vaz4DNJSpzaEMWsKcRQ%2FPMOioMi0lQ8Bg12bH3GhW%2FzaXlFUrAvSec3phCKH9jm7jHwPWbkEqmVjHmRUGZVurganr4qYtf3TB1PGNN7SrHnGGDOQn9pnxNlyGFwyuWnTvT%2Frh2wzgarhKncgzn%2F8uNVpZYUZSMzlWcHlXrMZxnxh49J6AisYQv5rlReq8gmRdT75653FioCnKekpp6Fq5jCXCngBxuRHR065ILa9Sxf5URyt5BPabxJelWdIqXI4XGw%2BoVPI9G7QsOIkhuKqBXyuEiCRN%2BZ2CqPV%2F7cJhcqzLPg8ZsYbNoPNtOoE%2F9ID%2FDqe8Oup3ngssF9geZM59CYJZRDX5m2k1tx%2BharW2E7WQO095tOV0uvtq1L%2BFKpiWm3V0cQ8C2ZXUBomwHRWIV%2BjAOf%2FKi7ytNyKTb%2BbsoOR95qmlLYXwmMDozDDqx8zhZ2cWFZdkRDS%2BLLm1%2FOIJiJfoVz4Z18%2BxLqxdt7XzvWKFioJiRXqyY023WVRUxR4fUcTjmB4iQM2asN1bNiyiMyr3JcOVtJSa4GtUDWP98ewPG3oYk6E6bUVeIlC%2BZ3cmj2VM%2BYwyu6gpQY6igKmRY%2F3aRMKO8b9afxOR%2BaZPGgWiZJ063U%2FPt2fBOB2CPFRQVIJB2Gb%2BMghuFAQt066eUU4i6wTU%2BfLYsG4mAj54fDmTNObFvi0ptKM7NS89gJ13BIPXDVSTay%2FFsQnpw%2BF3zlBI1f8u4DpXBqWff9WMv8hn%2FWSiZvS2M69XEfFFM1rzhW1bGf%2B7tXV5jM7upipz3cBjKACWTC%2FfKd3UqEvldi7RbhldUOnApX9LIdmiwuBZYDKXY%2F4ElAHnR7l8Syh3DoyNiu8zakYrT0bZmAbvJCaz3RMgydxCQGODFo8yNvN0LtU1ORN5SWrFWnP%2BvefC3a7XnTZOAu%2Bmun5m15K455af7rLoMT%2FWQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230707T235243Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21600&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQKBAMFBKM22NSNN2%2F20230707%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0847be3aa9864b1b1412c6acb3d56c9a38e76559349511b8d2f2ddbfd1c81b77
```

Whereas the URL generated from my boto3 python code looks like below:

```
https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cool-analysis-artifacts/0012d668-13c9-11ee-a2f0-5602f45624de/picture-4079.png?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCIAQKBAMFBKAIRALVWZ&Signature=123opx27AmUmffdnJayOQ7e%2BFpE%3D&Expires=1689378161
```

I think that's the reason why the boto3 generated URL cannot be used by the open public Internet users.

But I'm not able to figure out why and how to fix it.

Initially, I thought it's the credentials that I used that could have caused this, but this credential does have full S3 access.

And here's my Python code:

```
s3_client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                                 region_name='us-west-2',
                                 config=botocore.config.Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}),
                                 aws_access_key_id='access_key',
                                 aws_secret_access_key='secret_key'
                                 )
presigned_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket':'cool-analysis-artifacts', 'Key':'0012d668-13c9-11ee-a2f0-5602f45624de/picture-4079.png'}, ExpiresIn=MAXIMUM_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS)
```

UPDATE:

1. I'm able to run this command: `aws s3api list-objects --bucket cool-analysis-artifacts` which resulted a long list of json blobs, e.g. one

```
{
            "LastModified": "2023-06-15T18:38:30.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"abc12930ca127ee94938bbc39edf6\"",
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "abc-a24a53760417/cool-picture-199.png",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "cool-name",
                "ID": "abcde"
            },
            "Size": 12908
        }
```

2. I retried without `config=` when instantiating the s3_client, no difference is made.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Are you using Lambdas? EC2? What permissions does the access keys have? (Using the same credentials, can you run `aws s3api list-objects --bucket cool-analysis-artifacts`

Comment: Get rid of the `config` option to stop boto3 from using addressing style, there's little reason to use it here.

Comment: Thanks to you both! I've updated my OP to reflect this.